# Given $a$ and $b$, how many integers $0 \leq x < b$ satisfy $\text{gcd}(a, b) = \gcd(a + x, b)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Given $a$ and $b$, how many integers $0 \leq x < b$ satisfy
>   $\text{gcd}(a, b) = \gcd(a + x, b)$?

I've tried to solve this problem for quite a long time. I know that $ab = \gcd(a, b) \cdot \text{lcm}(a, b)$ and some other properties about GCD and LCM, but I really do not even know where to start.

I've also tried looking at the prime factors of $a$ and $b$, etc.

I don't need a closed formula for this but rather just a quick way to find this answer.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know the answer when $\gcd(a,b) = 1$?

Comment: I don't know the answer in this case. But I know this equality happens when $a$ and $b$ are coprime. I can find the prime factors of $a$ and $b$ and make sure there are none in common. I would still probably end up trying all values of $x$ between $0$ and $b$

Comment: Since $ab = \gcd(a,b)\cdot \text{lcm}(a,b)$ and $(a+x)b = \gcd(a+x,b)\cdot \text{lcm}(a+x,b) = \gcd(a,b)\cdot \text{lcm}(a+x,b)$ you have $\dfrac{a+x}{a} = \dfrac{ \text{lcm}(a+x,b)}{ \text{lcm}(a,b)}$. Does that help at all?

Comment: I meant, "do you know how many $x$ satisfy $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a+x,b)$" when $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer No, I do not know the answer to that case.

Comment: Okay. Regardless of $a$, the values $a + x$ for $0 \leqslant x < b$ form a complete residue system modulo $b$. How many numbers coprime to $b$ does a complete residue system contain?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not sure if it's so simple(?). For example, if $b = 7$, then it's $7$ ($0, 1, \ldots 6$), but this isn't always the case.

Comment: @DanielFischer would it be $b - \sigma_0(b)$ where $\sigma_0(x)$ is the number of divisors of $x$?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I agree with $b - \sigma_0(b)$ as well

Comment: this was a question in this online round https://codeforces.com/contest/1295 and I think problems asked in live contests should not be asked during the contest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\{ a + x : 0 \leqslant x < b\}$ is a set of $b$ consecutive integers, hence a complete residue system modulo $b$. The value $\gcd(y,b)$ depends only on the remainder of $y$ modulo $b$, thus the question is equivalent to

> For how many of the integers $1 \leqslant y \leqslant b$ is $\gcd(y,b) = \gcd(a,b)$?

If $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, the question is how many coprime resdiues to $b$ there are. The answer is $\varphi(b)$ by the definition of Euler's totient function $\varphi$.

For general $a$, let $d = \gcd(a,b)$ and write $b = d\cdot \beta$. Then $\gcd(y,b) = d$ implies $d \mid y$, hence we can write $y = d\cdot \eta$ with $\eta \leqslant \beta$, and
$$\gcd(d\eta, d\beta) = d \iff \gcd(\eta,\beta) = 1\,.$$

Thus the answer is that there are
$$\varphi\biggl(\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\biggr)$$
values $0 \leqslant x < b$ with $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a+x,b)$.